# How do you best refer to small, periodically released SQL scripts containing DML/DDL, archived in source control?

Tags: database, database-administration

Historically, when a project or team needs to create, update, or remove database resources, they will create an sql file, using a specific template, containing the required DML or DDL necessary to achieve the teams objective. These SQL files are commit to a single repository in source control by the project/feature teams, at which point a DBA will pick them up, evaluate, and deploy to the TEST and PROD databases as part of a scheduled release cycle.

We're currently re-inventing the release process as part of a larger project to modernize our databases and move into the cloud. As part of this project, we're looking to make any process improvements that can help along the way. For DML/DDL updates, we're automating the process in Github Actions. And here's were we bump into a semantics / nomenclature issue. These files have long been referred to as "**db patches**". This has always frustrated the DBA's who feel calling these files "patches" is overloading the term that should be reserved for security or other RDS engine patching.

We've all agree, in the next generation system, we won't call the DML/DDL files "patches", but we're struggling to come up with a better, more accurate, descriptive term. "**Migrations**" or "**Schema Migrations**" has been kicked around, but isn't loved since its sort of a mouthful, and could also be confused with our current usage of AWS "Database Migration Service" and the "Schema Conversion Tool" to convert, migrate, and synchronize our DB's into AWS.

Googling this question seems to only bring up "What is DDL vs DML" type pages and articles. I'm hoping to hear from the community what terms of are you are using! Thanks.

**TL;DR: What do you call files in source control that update the database?**